# date comparison not working correctly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class to a div if a certain date is 2 weeks or less from the current date. My logic is like this, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? It seems to be not doing the comparison correctly (it's adding the class to all divs) and I can't figure it out. Thanks for any help

```
function dateString () {
    var currentDate = new Date ();
    var twoWeeks = new Date ();
    twoWeeks.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 14)
    var EndDateDiv = $('.end-date');


    if (currentDate <= twoWeeks) { 
        EndDateDiv.addClass('red');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
function dateString () {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var twoWeeks = new Date();
    twoWeeks.setDate(twoWeeks.getDate() + 14);
    var limit = 15;
    var EndDateDiv = $('.end-date');
    var diff = Math.round((twoWeeks-currentDate)/(1000*60*60*24))
    if (diff > limit) { 
        EndDateDiv.addClass('red');
    }
};
```

working fiddle ==> https://jsfiddle.net/r1v34aty/

Answer (score 1):

It works as you expect. See the following snippet.

```js
dateString();
function dateString () {
    var currentDate = new Date ();
    var twoWeeks = new Date ();
    twoWeeks.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 14)
    var EndDateDiv = $('.end-date');


    if (currentDate <= twoWeeks) { 
        EndDateDiv.addClass('red');
        console.log($('.end-date').attr('class'));
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="end-date" />
```

Comment: Thank you for that, maybe I am going crazy (possible)

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
function dateString () {
    var currentDate = new Date ();
    var twoWeeks = new Date ();
    alert(twoWeeks);
    var EndDateDiv = $('.end-date');
    if (currentDate.getTime() <= twoWeeks.getTime()+(14*24*60*60)) { 
        EndDateDiv.addClass('red');
    console.log($('.end-date').attr('class'));      }
};
```